Rights and obligations of spouses if they still live with their parents
I learned from a previous fatwa that if you are a student and are not financially able to get married, you can still get married and both live with their parents until he is financially stable. My question is whether all rights and obligations of the spouses continue to exist during this time or whether this circumstance changes anything. Specifically, I am asking whether the husband has the right over his wife to have intercourse with her during this time. If not, please provide proof.

Not about religion, but the material question behind it: who will provide for the child from your intercourse? You cannot and she cannot.

Bro never heard of birth control

"my father says it doesn't work" ;-)
